# Return an array of date objects for each day in the month using javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, date

I am trying to return an array of date objects for each remaining day in the month.

However I cannot get the code to work for some reason, I know i'm pretty close but i've been stuck on this forever.

Here is my code:

```
function findDays(theDate, daysLeft) {
  var now = new Date();
  var date = now.getDate();
  var last = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();
  var daysLeft = last - date;
  return daysLeft;
}

var remaining = [];

var hello = function(daysLeft) {
  var daysLeft = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < daysLeft.length; i++) {
    remaining.push(
      new Date(year, month, day + i)
    );
  }
  return remaining;
};
// console.log(remaining);
// console.log(findDays() - (new Date(2016, 0, 1)).getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you set daysLeft = 0 which is not an array so calling daysLeft.length would yield undefined which means that you do not enter the loop at all.

Here is an edited code

```
function findDays(theDate, daysLeft) {
  var now = new Date();
  var date = now.getDate();
  var last = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();
  var daysLeft = last - date;
  return daysLeft;
}
var now = new Date();
for(var i=0; i<findDays(); i++){
    remaining.push(new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate() + i));
}
```

Comment: so how would I make this whole code return an array of date objects for each day left in the month?? im a bit confused

Comment: the code i wrote in my answer does what you want, for every month it pushes a date object in the array

Comment: for some reason the array is not displaying for me

Comment: I think i may be calling the function wrong, any idea of how to make it display properly with console.log?

Comment: after excuting the code do 
console.log(remaining);